# Unfortunately App has stopped with no verbose in logcat

Tags: android, runtime-error

I created an app with login activity and wanted to add an splash screen,I have added a java class and layout for the splash screen and bind the layout to the java class and run the app.

It doesn't run it show a dialog that says "unfortunately "my app" has stopped" and no verbose or any error appears in the logcat so i can't find where is the error !!! anyone can help,please??

[image: the logcat]

**my java class for splash screen**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public class Splash extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread myThread=new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                    Intent in =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

**logcat after editing :**

```
/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/InstantApps: DomainFilterImpl: Error while reading domain filter from WHAPI
                                                                              java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: axvq: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Application credential header not valid. Please fix the client to pass a valid application credential header.
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:93)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:163)
                                                                                  at tik.get(:com.google.android.gms:2099)
                                                                                  at tmd.a(:com.google.android.gms:347)
                                                                                  at tmd.a(:com.google.android.gms:313)
                                                                                  at tmd.a(:com.google.android.gms:131)
                                                                                  at tmd.b(:com.google.android.gms:101)
                                                                                  at tly.b(:com.google.android.gms:38)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.instantapps.routing.DomainFilterUpdateChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms:74)
                                                                                  at rml.run(:com.google.android.gms:261)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                               Caused by: axvq: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Application credential header not valid. Please fix the client to pass a valid application credential header.
                                                                                  at axvm.c(:com.google.android.gms:505)
                                                                                  at lgy.a(:com.google.android.gms:168)
                                                                                  at thx.b(:com.google.android.gms:7164)
                                                                                  at thx.a(:com.google.android.gms:57)
                                                                                  at til.call(:com.google.android.gms:1049)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                  at lmq.run(:com.google.android.gms:450)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                  at lra.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**manifest file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.com.example.abdelrahman.carcare">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CreatNew"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_creat_new">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            ></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

:

Comment: remove the firebase filter and put your stacktrace here

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra thank you the error appears ..
the logcat :
'com.google.android.gms.persistent E/InstantApps: DomainFilterImpl: Error while reading domain filter from WHAPI
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: axvq: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Application credential header not valid. Please fix the client to pass a valid application credential header '

Comment: please update your question and put  your code, what you've done so far?

Comment: @RuchaBhatt done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you can now only see logs from `Firebase`. Change it to `Show only Selected Application`

[image]